# Spring profile and property-placeholder exception

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use the profile to switch from an environment to another, this is my application context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <!--  Mongo config -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="${mongoHSRealtime.host.ip}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mongoHSRealtime.host.port}"/>
    </bean> 

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

    <!-- ###### ENVIRONMENET SPECIFIC SETTINGS ######### -->
    <beans profile="localhost">
        <bean id="deployProperties" p:location="classpath:localhost/spring.properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="dev">   
        <bean id="deployProperties" p:location="classpath:dev/spring.properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" />
    </beans>

</beans>
```

On the web.xml I defined which profile activate in this way:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/coreConfig/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:localhost/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profile.active</param-name>
    <param-value>localhost</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So, everything seems fine but, when I try to run tomcat, I get this exception:

```
11:47:01,098 AM CET ERROR ContextLoader @ initWebApplicationContext [353] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'deployProperties' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'deployProperties' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'deployProperties' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 24 more
```

Any clue? The properties file are in the correct position because I can reach using this configuration property **location** con **property-placeholder**.

Comment: perhaps you have to change the order of the context-params in your web.xml. first set the profile, second set the contextconfiglocation. or perhaps this help: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles

Comment: I would try to re-order the application context file, having the two profiles before  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />.

Comment: Probably missing `profile="dev"` within context parameter.

Comment: @Michal Nested <beans> must appear last in the file.

Comment: @Andrea: I was trying to say that reordering the beans definition might perhaps help. Does it run if you skip the profile stuff and try with just one of the deployProperties beans located at the end of the file?

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried using one of the two properties file and worked fined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `spring.profile.active` into `spring.profiles.active`.

Comment: That saves my day! Thanks a lot!