# Unable to resolve property placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am setting the location of two properties file in dispatcher servlet as :

```
<bean id="placeHolderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>file:local/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

application.properties has spring.profiles.active property.

When trying to deploy the application I am getting error like.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

**Edit** : The answers in the linked questions are not applicable my scenario because it requires me to change the web.xml for every environment change. I want this to be managed via the application.properties file

Comment: Well the cause is obvious - you're trying to use the placeholder when configuring the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` - cannot use it to initialize itself. Solution might be configuring more placeholder locations but with given order. But not sure about that.

Comment: @JiriTousek let me try it

Comment: You can use a `<bean profile="XXX">` around every possible placeholder each one with `file:local/application-XXX.properties`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869324/spring-profile-and-property-placeholder-exception) for example

Comment: @JiriTousek Dint worked

Comment: @RC. This will require me to change configuration file everytime.

Comment: you need to set  spring.profiles.active system property or pass on command line

Comment: Another wild guess, could you try this: `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" order="1" />` then `<context:property-placeholder location="file:local/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" order="2" />`. You'll need to import the `context` XSD, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JiriTousek Let me try

Comment: @RC. The question you mentioned requires me to change the web.xml for every environment change.

Comment: You should edit the question to add why the answers in the linked questions are not applicable to your scenario - cannot nominate for reopen otherwise.

Comment: @JiriTousek Ok have edited the question